# Insert text to text box using selenium chrome driver in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with this code

```html
<div id="mgmtStatic" class="initial_hide">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="mgmtIpAddr">IP Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mgmtIpAddr" id="mgmtIpAddr" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="mgmtIpNetmask">Netmask:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mgmtIpNetmask" id="mgmtIpNetmask" value="" />
  </div>
```

I use selenium with chrome driver to locate the IP Address text box using those methodes:

```
mngmntIP = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="mgmtIpAddr"][@value=""]')
```

and this:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("mgmtIpAddr")
```

and this

```
mngmntIP = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#mgmtIpAddr")
```

all of those methods locate that element but when i tried to insert txext to that box like this

```
mngmntIP = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="mgmtIpAddr"][@value=""]')
mngmntIP.clear()
mngmntIP.send_keys("192.168.1.11")
```

I do it using css_selector, also using id and name, all of them return  this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)`

Comment: Thank you Mr.Moshe Slavin, that is work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `WebDriverWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

mngmnt_ip = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mgmtIpAddr")))
mngmnt_ip.send_keys("192.168.1.11")
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing this:

```
mngmntIP.send_keys("192.168.1.11")
```

With this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '192.168.1.11';", mngmntIP)
```

This sets the element's value using Javascript instead of `send_keys`. I use it to work around the `ElementNotInteractable` error.