# Python ChromeDriver - How to type/write something on a textbox

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Hey i wanna build a automatic login/register python script.

But i dont know, how to type in a textbox or
find a textbox in the chromedriver.

I use selenium chrome.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839273/insert-text-to-text-box-using-selenium-chrome-driver-in-python-3